# Как использовать приложение на си в php

Tags: c#, c, php, c++

Добрый день!

Хочу сделать службу на c или с++/с#, чтобы при загрузке она брала данные из БД. И при обращении выдавались значения не из базы, а из службы, которая более быстро перебирает значения в оперативке.
И при изменении параметра (например, количество определённого товара на складе) оповестить других пользователей об этом.

Спасибо.

Comment: а Вы уже уперлись в производительность сервера? Или просто хочется проверить свои силы?

Для начала я бы писал на обычном php в виде rest сервиса, отладил. Если производительности не хватит, тогда можно и переписать.

Comment: А как сделать на php, чтоб работала служба и хранила в оперативке значения, а не вытягивала их из базы при каждом запросе?

Comment: возможно, Вам нужно узнать о [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)